# На debian 10 не запускается postman, установленный с помощью snap

Tags: linux, debian, postman

Всем привет. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, с чем может быть связан такой глюк (или где посмотреть, чтобы понять) - на debian 10 установил snapd, через snap установил postman, вроде поставился нормально, но он не запускается. В тупик ставит то, что сообщений об ошибках не возникает. Будто бы процесс просто запускается и сразу же завершается.

```
vadim@vadim:~$ snap info postman
name:      postman
summary:   API Development Environment
publisher: Postman, Inc. (postman-inc✓)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/postman
contact:   https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues
license:   unset
description: |
  Postman is the collaboration platform for API development, used by 8 million developers and
  400,000 companies worldwide. Postman is an elegant, flexible tool for building connected software
  via APIs quickly, easily, and accurately. Postman is a global company with headquarters in San
  Francisco, a large office in Bangalore (where the company was founded), and distributed team
  members on four continents. Postman is privately held, with funding from Nexus Venture Partners
  and CRV.
commands:
  - postman
snap-id:      fFcOtEEF4EdyYb95IUE5Isy28tICYMLf
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 19:26 MSK
channels:
  latest/stable:    7.22.1 2020-04-09 (106) 154MB -
  latest/candidate: 7.22.1 2020-04-09 (106) 154MB -
  latest/beta:      7.22.1 2020-04-09 (106) 154MB -
  latest/edge:      7.22.1 2020-04-09 (106) 154MB -
  v6/stable:        6.7.6  2019-10-23  (95) 138MB -
  v6/candidate:     ↑                             
  v6/beta:          ↑                             
  v6/edge:          ↑                             
installed:          7.22.1            (106) 154MB -
```